# Run `flutter clean` command on each project in a directory

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

As a Flutter developer, I've been working on many projects. I have to work on all of them occasionally. Now those projects lie in a single directory occupying 30+ GB on my drive. It'd be a good idea to have the project's build-cache deleted to save some space. So I figured to write a script that would loop through each of them and run `flutter clean` inside every folder instead of running the command manually under each project's root.

After Google and StackOverflow search I came up with a command :

`for /D %G in ("D:\MyProjects\*") do flutter clean "%~fG"`

Well this command executes the flutter clean command for each folder like:

```
C:\Users\vipin>flutter clean "D:\MyProjects\Project1"
C:\Users\vipin>flutter clean "D:\MyProjects\Project2"
C:\Users\vipin>flutter clean "D:\MyProjects\Project3"
C:\Users\vipin>flutter clean "D:\MyProjects\Project4"
```

This should have worked since the command states to run `flutter clean` for each folder as it looked. Unfortunately, it didn't and threw error:

```
C:\Users\vipin>flutter clean "D:\MyProjects\Project1"
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

C:\Users\vipin>flutter clean "D:\MyProjects\Project2"
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

C:\Users\vipin>flutter clean "D:\MyProjects\Project3"
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

C:\Users\vipin>flutter clean "D:\MyProjects\Project4"
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
...
```

Well, the pubspec.yaml files are very much present in each folder and I figured that the `flutter clean` command demands your prompt pointing to Project's ROOT, like below to do the job:

```
D:\Myprojects\Project1>flutter clean
```

Now I'm looking for a command/script anything to move the command's prompt to each project's root and execute the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glad you asked. I had the same thought about doing it to my list of projects. The below command will do exactly what you expect. Make sure to run this from D:\MyProjects

`for /d %i in (D:\MyProjects\*) do ( cd "%i" &  flutter clean )`

Answer (score 7):

in case someone was looking for **MacOs / Linux** version :

```bash
for dir in ~/dev/* ; do (cd "$dir" && flutter clean ); done
```

*note: change the main path for your porject instead of `~/dev` and leave the `/*` at the end of it*

Answer (score 0):

*I did it like this on my Mac:*

You can achieve this by using a combination of `find` and `xargs` commands in the terminal on Mac. Here's how you can run the `flutter clean` command for each subdirectory in a specific directory:

1. Open the Terminal app on your Mac. You can find it in the Utilities folder within the Applications folder.
2. Navigate to the specific directory where you want to run the `flutter clean` command for each subdirectory. For example, if your directory is located at `/path/to/your/directory`, you would type:

   ```bash
   cd /path/to/your/directory
   ```
3. Once you're in the desired directory, run the following command:

   ```bash
   find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '(cd "{}" && echo "Cleaning in $(pwd)" && flutter clean)' \;
   ```

   Let's break down this command:

   - `find .`: Searches for files and directories starting from the current directory (`.`).
   - `-maxdepth 1`: Restricts the search to only the immediate subdirectories (depth level 1).
   - `-mindepth 1`: Excludes the current directory itself from the search.
   - `-type d`: Specifies that only directories should be considered.
   - `-exec sh -c '...' \;`: Executes the specified shell command (`sh -c '...'`) for each found directory.
4. Press Enter to run the command.

This command will execute `flutter clean` within each subdirectory of the specified directory, providing you with a clean build environment for each Flutter project within those subdirectories.